# R Removing an element of a list element

Tags: r, list, indexing

This is more a general question on the behavior of lists in R, but the specific problem is:

I have a list of groups of words which I'm trying to manually remove specific words for - where no word is mentioned twice.

Currently, I'm using this method

```
l = strsplit(c("a b", "c d"), " ")

> l
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[2]]
[1] "c" "d"

# remove the value "d"
l = lapply(l, function(x) { x[x != "d"] })

> l
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[2]]
[1] "c"
```

Is there any sort of built in list indexing method that would be preferable to use? I feel like I should just be able to parse the list without using `lapply`. If not, is it possible that someone could explain why this is the case?

Thanks

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear. Do you care to keep c("a", "b") from the first string separate from c("c", "d") from the second? If not, you can do x=unlist(l) and then x=x[x!="d"]. Otherwise, you will either have the operation element by element, or construct a data structure where you keep information of which string the individual pieces correspond to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go through each element of the list and check if the vector contains `d` to filter/remove it. 
One of the reason is that a list can contains various type of data (`functions`, `data.frame`, `numeric`, `character`, `boolean`, other `lists`, `class`) so there can't be `vectorized` operations (which are - as suggests the name - for vectors).

What you do is to filter you filter on the front end - eg when you have the list. It could be preferable to filter in the back end your vector, eg *before* obtaining the `list`:

```
l = strsplit(gsub('d','',c("a b", "c d")), " ")
#[[1]]
#[1] "a" "b"

#[[2]]
#[1] "c"
```

Some alternative solution for a front end filtering:

```
lapply(l, grep, pattern='[^d]', value=T)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. One additional thing though - I've had to do a fair bit of coercing to get the data in to the list format, the `strsplit(c("a b", "c d"), " ")` was just in interest of an example. If I simply have a list `l` as above, and I want to remove `"d"` is the best option still just back-end filtering/what I've done?

Comment: Yes, your approach is totally valid! In case I added an alternative with `grep` in order not to write a function.